# Elasticsearch from a .net developer perspective

Tags: elasticsearch

i've just started to learn elasticsearch and even if i'm reading the documentation and do understand some aspects i have a long way to go until i will at least at some degree feel comfortable using it. The problem i'm having is that i don't understand if trying to use and integrate elastic with a .net project , will i'll still be needing a DB (relational) to have all of my date ? or i will not need it anymore since with elastic i can create indexes (which from my understanding is sort of a DB all by itself) that are stored on nodes which make a cluster so basically my date resides on a cluster at the end.

Can you give me a simple explanation with a simple example? I'm trying to implement a search page , this is my use case and elastic seems to know it's way around with searching stuff.

Thank you all.

Comment: Search is very efficient with Elastic because (among other reasons) ALL the data is indexed and stored in memory. Relational DB are usually (except H2 etc) working with disks and (most of the time) smaller memory buffers. Problem is memory is more expensive than disk space. Check Elastic hardware requirements https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/hardware.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data will be persisted physically in each node of the cluster under the /data folder.
Ideally you'll do [regular backups](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/backing-up-your-cluster.html).

As an example I suggest this (working on a cluster with one single node) :

- Start elastic and [put some data in it](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/create-doc.html).
- Backup then delete the /data folder. You can't [find the data](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/get-doc.html) anymore.
- Put the folder back and [do a get](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/get-doc.html). It works !

Comment: ok so from what i understand here is the fact that the relational db will not be needed anymore? all operations get/delete/update/insert whatever will be against the cluster ?

Comment: @XulescuXulescuXulesc Indeed. No relational DB. Just a lot of data in RAM and in files on your hard drive.